# Find matching first 7 chars to identify duplicates

Tags: sql, informix

I'm trying to identify duplicate `state_num` that are failing validation. The **R** is causing issues with validation, but I want to just search the first 7 characters and find the duplicate values, so that it returns the row that has an **R** in the string and the row that doesn't. The column is a type: char(15) But when trying to run a query it is not finding the matching 7 characters. My table only showing how it should look, its not showing what is actually being returned. It basically is just finding the state and only finding non **R** `state_num` in results. It should be returning around 480 rows but is returning like 20k rows and not just showing the duplicates

I've tried querying a bunch of different ways but i've spen the last hour only being able to return the R row if i ad `AND state_num[8] = 'R'` to the end of the query. Which defeats what I'm trying to find the duplicate first 7 characters. This is an informix db.

My Query:

```
SELECT id_ref, cont_ref, formatted, state_num, type, state
FROM state_form sf1
WHERE EXISTS (select cont_ref, san
  FROM state_form sf2
  WHERE sf1.cont_ref = sf2.cont_ref and left(sf1.state_num,7) = LEFT(sf2.state_num,7)
 GROUP BY cont_ref, state_num
 HAVING COUNT(state_num) > 1)
 AND state = 'MT';
```

This is what I'd like my results to return:

| id_ref | cont_ref | formatted | state_num | type | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 658311 | 5237 | 71-75011R | 7175011R | Y | MT |
| 1459 | 5237 | 71-75011 | 7175011 | I | MT |
| 7501 | 555678 | 99-67894 | 9967894 | I | MT |
| 345443 | 555678 | 99-67894R | 9967894R | Y | MT |

Comment: Tip of today: Qualify _all_ columns! `WHERE cont_ref = cont_ref` will (almost) always be true. (I.e. as long as cont_ref is not null.) Use different column aliases for the two state_form instances. Do `sf1.cont_ref = sf2.cont_ref`.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for pointing that out. I updated with the aliases. You're right the `cont_ref` will always match. I'm narrowing down my search to a specific state. Guess I'm stumped as to how i can pull out those first 7 characters and see if there are duplicates. I can query all and export to excel to find but not sure how to accomplish this with SQL.

Comment: Does "R" matter here? Like can it 1234567T and 1234567 are also considered a duplicate? Or would about 7654321 and 76543210?

Comment: @Isolated no R doesn't matter there are other letters i just want it to match first 7 characters with or without the next character. It will accept 15 characters but only worried about finding both 1234567 and 1234567T or 1234567R.

Comment: @Isolated I think that is close. the left function in the `group by` .  Informix doesn't seem to like. Getting std syntax error at the left function. I'll search but I think that is pretty close.

Comment: Just updated the answer if group by is causing a problem.

Comment: @Isolated i'm trying to get the target state_num that match everything up to the 7th postion anything after is fine and can return. I just want to be able to view it. There is like 40k records for that state in that table. It just needs to have the same cont_ref. We have seen when file was read it imported a letter after that 7th char. We want to identify and make the `rec_type` invalid = `I` if it has a dupe with letter. I will play around with what you showed. I see the fiddle returning but cte isn't allow in informix. Thank you for your time and responses. It got me a little further.

Comment: @isolated I got this to work thank you. Informix 11.x doesn't allow cte but 14 does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple options producing the same results. This may need to be changed if you need to identify the 8th character as something such as a Letter. That is, this will also catch 12345678 and 1234567.

```
create table my_data (
  id_ref integer, 
  cont_ref integer, 
  state_num varchar(20), 
  type varchar(5), 
  state varchar(5)
  );
  
 insert into my_data values 
 (1, 5237, '7175011R', 'Y', 'MT'),
 (2, 5237, '7175011', 'I', 'MT'),
 (3, 6789, '7878787', 'Y', 'CA'),
 (4, 6789, '7878787R', 'I', 'CA'),
 (5, 555678, '9967894', 'I', 'MT'),
 (6, 555678, '9967894R', 'Y', 'MT'),
 (7, 98765, '123456', 'I', 'MT');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with dupes as (
  select cont_ref
  from my_data
  where state = 'MT'
  group by cont_ref, left(state_num, 7)
  having count(*) > 1
  )
select m.id_ref, m.cont_ref, m.state_num, m.type, m.state
from my_data m
join dupes d
  on m.cont_ref = d.cont_ref;
```

---

**Query #2**

```
select m.id_ref, m.cont_ref, m.state_num, m.type, m.state
from my_data m
where m.cont_ref in (
  select cont_ref
  from my_data
  where state = 'MT'
  group by cont_ref, left(state_num, 7)
  having count(*) > 1
  );
```

| id_ref | cont_ref | state_num | type | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5237 | 7175011R | Y | MT |
| 2 | 5237 | 7175011 | I | MT |
| 5 | 555678 | 9967894 | I | MT |
| 6 | 555678 | 9967894R | Y | MT |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oYwkXUiqS7uZoztCqSjF3n/0)

**UPDATE**

If Informix does not want to group by left(column, 7), then you could get the target cont_ref values using this. Here's the CTE method, but you could also do with sub-query.

```
with dupes as (
 select cont_ref
 from (
   select cont_ref, left(state_num, 7) as left_seven
   from my_data
   where state = 'MT'
   )z
 group by cont_ref
 having count(*) > 1
)
select m.*
from my_data m
join dupes d
  on m.cont_ref = d.cont_ref;
```

Comment: i'm trying to get the target `state_num` that match everything up to the 7th postion anything after is fine. It just needs to have the same cont_ref